# Proguard is not Doing Anything

Tags: android

I've set up proguard according to this link: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/proguard-android-and-licensing-server.html

When I build with Ant I get no errors or warnings, but I also don't get any verbose output telling me that ProGuard is doing anything. By other means I'm able to tell that the apk is not being obfuscated.

All of my code, with the exception of the Activity class is in a library (as source files). I've read that the activity class will not obfuscated, but I'm wondering if I have to set up something different in my build files to include the library files?

Comment: I have the same problem. It seems that somehow the configuration is not correct on our machines.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove the debug line from your manifest?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old link.
Assuming you've downloaded the ADT plugin and the SDK this year, Proguard is bundled in the build process.
All you have to do is add this to default.properties:

```
proguard.config=proguard.cfg
```

Note that the obfuscation will occur only when you export a final version and not on every build.

Comment: one question...will proguard run when i export app in a eclipse wizard? And do you know do i need to put something for billing, because i use it in my app?! Thanks in advance...

Comment: No, proguard will not run when you export the app through Eclipse. You need to build the executable on the command-line using ant by typing "ant release" without the parentheses.

Comment: Proguard will run when you export the app only if you do what I wrote in my answer.